# How to open url in external browser on Tap on android push notifications?

Tags: java, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am trying to open the browser with a url when the user click on the push notification, i search in stackoverflow and i find this

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
```

but it doesnt work for me.
I am searching for the solution for last 5 days but failed to find the one.
Here is my code

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {


@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

// Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.android"));
startActivity(notificationIntent);


notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,
PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

int notificationId = new Random().nextInt(60000);
Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapfromUrl(remoteMessage.getData().get("image-url"));

Intent likeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
likeIntent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID_EXTRA,notificationId);
likeIntent.putExtra(IMAGE_URL_EXTRA,remoteMessage.getData().get("image-url"));
PendingIntent likePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this,
notificationId+1,likeIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
notificationManager =
(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
setupChannels();
}

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID)
.setLargeIcon(bitmap)
.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
.setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"))
.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
.setSummaryText(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"))
.bigPicture(bitmap))/*Notification with Image*/
.setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"))
.setAutoCancel(true)
.setSound(defaultSoundUri)
.addAction(R.drawable.ic_favorite_true,
getString(R.string.notification_add_to_cart_button),likePendingIntent)
.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());

}
```

Looking for any help..

Comment: The problem is that it open playmarket instead of web browser?

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you have tried so far is pretty correct. I've tried your code on a sample android app,

```
package com.example.notificationapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "Notification Channel Name";
    private static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME = "Notifications";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.android"));
        startActivity(notificationIntent);

        notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        int notificationId = new Random().nextInt(60000);
//        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapfromUrl(remoteMessage.getData().get("image-url"));

//        Intent likeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
//        likeIntent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID_EXTRA,notificationId);
//        likeIntent.putExtra(IMAGE_URL_EXTRA, remoteMessage.getData().get("image-url"));
//        PendingIntent likePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this,
//                notificationId+1,likeIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            final NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
                    NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                        //.setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("some random title")
//                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
//                                .setSummaryText("message from remote message")
//                                .bigPicture(bitmap))/*Notification with Image*/
                        .setContentText("Adding some text within content text")
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
//                        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_favorite_true,
//                                getString(R.string.notification_add_to_cart_button),likePendingIntent)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

This is what I see,

[image]

So I see the browser is getting opened with the url specified.

I highly suspect your `onMessageReceived` method within MyFirebaseMessagingService is not invoked. Please add a log message within onMessageReceived and see if you are getting invoked that can possibly be the next thing to do if you haven't tried already.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this snippet and It's working well:

```
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)
    Log.d("TAG", "From: ${remoteMessage.from}")

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.data.isNotEmpty()) {
        Log.i("TAG", "Message data payload: ${remoteMessage.data}")

    }

    if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
        handleNow(remoteMessage)
    }
    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    remoteMessage.notification?.let {
        Log.d("TAG", "Message Notification Body: ${it.body}")
    }

    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
}

private fun handleNow(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    try {
        val mBuilder =
            NotificationCompat.Builder(
                applicationContext,
                "notify_001"
            )
        var intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
                        "market://details?id=" + applicationContext.packageName))
        intent.action = "Unique_id"
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            applicationContext, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )

        val bigText =
            NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()

        for (item in remoteMessage.data.keys) {
            Log.i("TAG", "Key:" + item + " " + remoteMessage.data[item])
        }
        if (remoteMessage.data["big_text"] != null) {
            bigText.bigText(remoteMessage.data["big_text"])
        }
        if (remoteMessage.data["big_content_title"] != null) {
            bigText.setBigContentTitle(remoteMessage.data["big_content_title"])
        }
        if (remoteMessage.data["summary_text"] != null) {
            bigText.setBigContentTitle(remoteMessage.data["summary_text"])
        }a
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        mBuilder.setContentTitle(remoteMessage.notification?.title)
        mBuilder.setContentText(remoteMessage.notification?.body)
        mBuilder.priority = NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        val bitmap =
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                applicationContext.getResources(),
                R.drawable.chandmahame_logo
            )
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setLargeIcon(bitmap)
        mBuilder.setStyle(bigText)
        val mNotificationManager: NotificationManager = applicationContext
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channelId = "1234"
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                channelId, "YOUR_CHANNEL_ID",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            )
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
            mBuilder.setChannelId(channelId)
        }

        mNotificationManager.notify(
            NOTIFICATION_ID,
            mBuilder.build()
        )
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

and for sure, using it as Java code is not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

I search in tutorialpoint.com and appear this with a button, maybe can help.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```